# Causative form + te form + another verb construction

Tags: verbs, syntax, て-form, causation

In this specific case:

> 取らせて頂いた

So, what's the meaning of such a construction? I understand what each thing does alone (the causative form, the te form and the verb in past indicative), But what happens when we jumble it all together?

For context, the complete phrase I'm trying to understand is:

> その時々で取らせて頂いた先生方のデータです

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「～～させ (causative verb form) + て + いただく」 expresses receiving the permission (or opportunity) to perform an action from another person.

「いただく」 ＝ 「もらう」 in meaning.  Former is only politer than the latter.

> 「[取]{と}らせていただいた」 means "I/We received the permission to take/collect ~~."
>
> One could also use as a translation "I/We had the pleasure of taking/collecting ~~."

＊Note that I personally do not write supplementary verbs (in this case, いただく) in kanji.  That is actually the rule both in schools and the printed media.

> 「その[時々]{ときどき}で取らせていただいた[先生方]{せんせいがた}のデータです。」, therefore, means:
>
> "These are the data from (or "on") the teachers that I/we had the pleasure of collecting at different times."

(Without further context, one could not tell if it is "from" or "on/regarding".)